# My phone is about to dead

Tags: grammar

> My phone is dead

It means cellphone's battery is totally ran out.

> **My phone is about to dead.**

Can I say this way if the battery is around 5-10%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are some natural ways to say this:

> My phone is **about to die**
>
> My phone is **almost dead**
>
> My phone is **going to die** soon.

You could also say, *"My phone is about to be dead"* if you wanted to emphasize (or possibly *dramatize*) the impending death of your phone.

"About to dead" is not grammatical in any context.  You need to use the infinitive form of the verb:

> She is about **to leave**
>
> They are about **to eat**
>
> We are about **to have** dinner.

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'm guessing it's on the grammar of the second one, so I'll answer that.

You would use the verb "die" on the second one: "My phone is about to die."

You could also use the past tense/past participle of "die", which is "died", just with different words: "My phone has died."

In conclusion, use "die".